# Python sqlalchemy error filter_by "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to list exercises within a specific muscle group. However, when I click an image passing group id I get "IndexError: list index out of range" error.

Muscle Group Html
(mgroup.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {% for group in groups %}
      <a href="{{ url_for('exercises.exig', id=group.id)}}">
      <img class="" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='ex_pic/' + group.gimage)}}" alt="" a width="350" height="250">
      </a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Exercises in muscle group Html (exig.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block app_content %}
  <div class="col-md-5">
    {% for e in ex %}
    <p>{{ e }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

routes.py

```
@exercises.route('/muscle_groups')
def mgroup():
    groups = Musclegroup.query.order_by(Musclegroup.group.asc())
    return render_template('exercises/mgroup.html', title='Muscle Groups', groups=groups)


@exercises.route('/exercises/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def exig(id):
    ex = [e.exercises.order_by(Exercises.all()) for e in Musclegroup.query.filter_by(group=id)][0]
    return render_template('exercises/exig.html', title='Exercises', ex=ex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error, the list you build with `[e.exercises.order_by(Exercises.all()) for e in Musclegroup.query.filter_by(group=id)][0]` appears to be empty, such that you are attempting to index into `[][0]`, which throws the error. This is because The `filter_by` method returns a BaseQuery object and not the actual matches, you need to add an `all()` call to get the results:

```
ex = [e.exercises.order_by(Exercises.all()) for e in Musclegroup.query.filter_by(group=id).all()][0]
```